# Ошибка при работе Doxygen 1.8.6?

Tags: doxygen

При генерации документа с помощью Doxygen выдаётся куча сообщений об ошибках вида:

> warning: unable to resolve reference to `get_rangingOffset' for \ref command

При более внимательном рассмотрении проблемы оказалось, что Doxygen не видит вообще ни  одной функции/метода, кроме `main()`. Порывшись в сети обнаружил, что эта проблема появилась на версии Doxygen 1.8.6. У меня сейчас стоит именно эта версия. Однако, странность заключается в том, что проект на С он обрабатывает абсолютно нормально, а на С++ наблюдается такая вот ерунда...

Похоже, дело в том. что в С нет namespace, а на С++ я его использую. Т.е. синтаксис Doxygena надо как-то сопоставить с синтаксисом С++.

Есть какие-то идеи?

Answer (score 2):

Причина была именно в namespace ! По своей внутренней логике, `Doxygen` документирует любой элемент текста программы только в том случае, если программист задокументировал (**обязательно!**) объемлющий элемент.

Так как мои функции были включены в некое namespace, то Doxygen ожидал, что я откомментирую это самое namespace! Как только я это сделал, вот так:

```
/** Пространство модуля конфигурации
 *
 * В этом пространстве расположены все функции модуля конфигурации
 * - readCfgFile - Обработать файл конфигурации
 * - freeCfgFile - Освободить память
 */
namespace wimicConfig
{
```

всё сразу заработало отлично.